# What is difference between had done and had did?

Tags: tense, past-tense

What is the difference between "had done" and "had did" ?

> John had done this/it

and

> John had did this/it

Comment: #1 is fine, #2 is ungrammatical.

Comment: @Robusto why second is grammatically incorrect ?

Comment: Because the past participle of *do* is *done*, not *did*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, as long as we are referring to an action in the past, we can say, **"John had done it."**, the past perfect form.

However, **"John had did it"** is incorrect. To form the past perfect, we need to use the past participle of **"To do"**, which is **"Done"**

Note that using **"This"** implies a connection to the present, so the present perfect is required.

Comment: Ok What if it was "it" instead of "this" ? Then what will be the difference.

Comment: In the first sentence, using "it" and the past perfect would be OK as long as the action is relative to the past, like writing a story in the past tense. However, the second is still incorrect. "Did" is not the past participle of "To do".

Comment: Ok got it now. Can you please update this in your answer too.